# Clang/g++ options for template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, explicit-instantiation

I'm looking for a compiler option on g++/clang++ to control the instantiation of methods in explicit instantiations.

Suppose I have a classtemplate `Foo<T>` with some explicit instantiation

```
template Foo<int>;
```

I want to enable the instantiation of all public methods. This doesn't seem to be the default, as I'm having to add manual instantiations for all the members in order to avoid link errors;

```
template void Foo<int>:DoStuff(int);
template int Foo<int>:GetSomeStuff();
```

Comment: `template Foo<int>` doesn't do anything (it's actually an error in gcc). You want `template class Foo<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either instantiate each method individually or you would instantiate all of them for the class. It seems you want to do the latter but the notation you tried is wrong. The correct one is this:

```
template class Foo<int>;
```

(assuming `Foo` is declared as a `class`; if it is declared as a `struct` you'd use the `struct` keyword instead).